# Passing a custom variable from preprocess view to a template file

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am preprocessing a view in order to create a custom variable and then pass it to a view template file.

I have added the following code to the template.php file:

```
function mycustomtheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    $view = $vars['view'];

    $currentpath = current_path();
    $path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$currentpath);

    // define the custom variable
    $vars['mycustomvariable'] = '';

    if ($view->name == 'mycustomviewname') {

        foreach($view->result as $key => $result) {
            $tid = $result->tid; // get the taxonomy term's ID
            $termpath = drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $tid); // term's path
            // if the current path is same to the one of the term
            if ($termpath == $path_alias) {
                // give a value to the custom variable
                $vars['mycustomvariable'] = 'blablabla';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the views-view-list--mycustomviewname--block_1.tpl.php file, I try to print the variable like this:

```
<?php print $mycustomvariable; ?>
```

But I am getting the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mycustomvariable in include() (line 18 of
>   views-view-list--mycustomviewname--block_1.tpl.php)

I have spent a considerable amount of time on this issue and used dpm and print_r to print out variables, arrays and objects but I cannot seem to find solution to this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the `if ($termpath == $path_alias)` condition holds?

Comment: @Drupalist Yes the condition is met. I tested it by printing out something when it's met and it works. I also tried to print the custom variable outside the if clause, but I still get the same error. Any clues?

Comment: are you sure the variable is being assigned correctly - what does a dpm() of the $vars at the end of the function show for the variable?

Comment: @Geoff a `dpm($vars)` right after `$vars['mycustomvariable'] = 'blablabla';` gives "mycustomvariable (String, 9 characters ) blablabla". So, I am guessing the variable is correctly assigned to the custom variable. So, is my way of trying to print the variable inside the template file wrong or am I missing something else? Thank you for your help.

Comment: assuming $vars has at least one thing assigned before this function, it should contain more than that one variable - it could be reassigning a local variable, instead of the $vars being given to the function as an argument. Try a dpm of $vars as the first line of the function, and again as the last line of the function - is the new value assigned for the latter version of $vars?

Comment: template_preprocess_views_view preprocesses variables for views-view.tpl.php. It looks like your view has a template based on views-view-list.tpl.php. Try using mytheme_preprocess_views_view_list instead of mytheme_preprocess_views_view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure what I'm going to tell you is completely true, it is just my experience of how Views works.

From what I know, Every preprocess function has access to a specific `output` template file. As an example variables of `template_preprocess_views_view_fields` are available in `views-view-fields--AnyThingElse.tpl.php` template file, so the domain access of variables of `template_preprocess_views_view_fields` is `views-view-fields--AnyThingElse.tpl.php`.

In *Theme Information* there are three levels of output styles:

1. Display output
2. Style output
3. Row style output

The `views-view-list--mycustomviewname--block_1.tpl.php` is a TPL file in the second level (`Style output`) but I guess the `mycustomtheme_preprocess_views_view` domain of access of its variables is in the first level (`Display output`) TPL files.

To make sure, select one of the TPL files from `Display output` and check if the variable is set in there.

Comment: Nice explanation @Drupalist